# Insert many to many in Codeigniter with join

Tags: codeigniter, join, many-to-many

I'm using Codeiginter to implement small project, I'm stuck with many to many idea.

The problem is: If I have these entities

---

**users**(u_id,name)

**cars**(c_id,model)

**users_cars**(uc_id,u_id,c_id)

---

And the user number 1 choose 3 cars model using checkbox, for example (1,2,3) model1 model2 model3.

How can I implement this in Codeigniter? the (users_cars) entity should be (1,1,1)(2,1,2)(3,1,3).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet so I'm writing here. But this is either just a case of multidimensional array creation or I do not understand the question

for each of the checkboxes :

```
users_cars = array(uc_id, u_id, c_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

first on you create checkbox in array like

```
<input type='checkbox' name="cars[]" value='c_id'>
```

submit the form in controller and get posted data..

```
$cars=$this->input->post('cars');
$u_id=$this->input->post('u_id');
for($i=0;i<=count($cars);i++ ){
  $insert=array('u_id'=>$u_id,'c_id'=>$cars[$i]);
  $this->db->insert('users_cars',$insert);
}
```